# What is 'upsert' in the context of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

In the context of MongoDB, what is upsert?

Is this an update and insert?

Just curious as I see the usage of this term in many articles and documentation on the MongoDB website.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation: An operation that will either update the first document matched by a query or insert a new document if none matches. The new document will have the fields implied by the operation.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-upsert

Answer (score 1):

To put it into SQL terms it is much like a `ON DUPLICATE KEY ... UPDATE` except that it isn't so verbose in how to query for it.

So essentially it is when you query for an update document, MongoDB doesn't find it and so inserts it.

The condition for the upsert accepts all the same stuff as a normal update except it also has the `$setOnInsert` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/ ) operator which allows you to define a set of fields that will only be taken into consideration on an insert.